# Finding number of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, solution-verification, determinant

The number of solutions of the equations

$x_{2}-x_{3}=1$

$-x_{1}+2x_{3}=2$

$x_{1}-2 x_{2}=3$

### (a) zero
(b) one
(c) two
(d) infinite

**In a solution,I saw**
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text 
{ Let } \Delta=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & 0
\end{array}\right| \\
=-1(-2)-1(2)=0
\end{array}
$$
Hence given system of equations is consistent and since have no two equations are identical, therefore number of solutions is one.
So
$\boxed{Ans. (b)}$

---

**My approach**

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0 & +1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right]$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0 & 1 & -1 & . & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 2 & . & 2 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 & . & 5\end{array}\right] \quad \quad R_{3}=R_{2}+R_{3}$

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 7\end{array}\right] \quad R_{3}=2 R_{1}+R_{3}$

$\rho(A) \neq \rho(A \mid B)$

So NO Solution

*I am getting a contradiction.*
**Am I wrong**

Comment: Why $12$ in the 3rd row of the first matrix after "my approach" (?)

Comment: Your first conclusion  is wrong. Zero determinant says that (a) or (d) is true.

Comment: As $\Delta =0$ and $\Delta_1,\,\Delta_2,\,\Delta_3 \ne 0$, the system of equations has no solutions.

Comment: So the ans I am getting with my approach is correct??

Comment: @AmartyaRoy It is correct but the numbers are wrong. See my first comment, that $12$ should be a $-2$. Edit: I just noticed you only wrote $12$ there and then used $-2$ so yes, it's correct